# Converting row level information into columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, stack, pivot, transpose

Currently I have a dataframe(df), which is at a category-subcategory level. The target variable is at category level. I want to represent the subcategories as columns, so that dataframe would be at a category level and the target variable would be unique to each row item.

catprop1 and catprop2 are category level properties and subcatprop1 and subcatprop2 are subcategory level properties. 'Category target' is the target variable which is at a category level.
My current data frame is like this

[image]

I want to convert that into the below format by representing sub-category level information as columns as below.

[image]

Any help in getting this done is appreciated.
I am not sure about the usage of pivot, and the examples I saw is not useful in this context. This involves renaming and flattening the dataframe.

Comment: Assuming that `CAT ID` and `subcatid` form a MultiIndex of the DataFrame, would `df.unstack()` give the right result?

Comment: It is not a multiIndexed dataframe

Comment: Can you make it into one? `df.set_index(["CAT ID", "subcatid"])`